# KnockoutJS - Is there any easy way to overwrite observables with a single object?

Tags: knockout.js

Consider the following code:

```
 // data comes from AJAX call response (entity from db)
 var template = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

 if ( isAddMode ) {                            
     self.selectedCategory().EmailTemplates.push(template);
     self.selectedTemplate(template);
 } else {
     // why can't this work?!?
     //vmTemplates.selectedTemplate(template);                   

     // have to do this instead...
     self.selectedTemplate().Name(template.Name());
     self.selectedTemplate().Subject(template.Subject());
     self.selectedTemplate().Content(template.Content());
}
```

I have a dialog to edit an email template.  When the template is saved, the 'template' object is created from the response from the AJAX call using the mapping plugin.

If I am creating a new template (isAddMode), then I can push the template onto to the array and then set the selectedTemplate().  This results in the editor fields showing all the up-to-date fields on the main UI after the dialog to add the template has closed.

However, if I'm UPDATING the template (which is the same editor on the UI), I'd like to now set the selectedTemplate() to the mapped template object.  However this has no effect. The only way I can achieve this is to set every individual property as above.  Why can I not do this in one go like when I push a new observable?  I feel like it has something to do with the fact that the new observables are somehow detached from the old ones.

Comment: Can you reproduce that behavior in a fiddle? Seems to work for me so far: http://jsfiddle.net/sU22b/

Comment: Why is the commented out one `vmTemplates` and not `self` like the rest?

Comment: vmTemplates is the variable holding the model, self is a reference to 'this' within the model so it shouldn't matter which version I use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(template,self.selectedTemplate);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

try to push it

```
// data comes from AJAX call response (entity from db)
var template = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

if (isAddMode) {
    self.selectedCategory().EmailTemplates.push(template);
    self.selectedTemplate(template);
} else {
    // why can't this work?!?
    //vmTemplates.selectedTemplate(template);                   

    // try it!
    self.selectedTemplate.Push(template);
}
```